# Select different values from different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `cad_changes`:

```
id          unit_id      old_value    new_value   change_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------
4615128     800          88809433      83028302   2018-03-01 17:02:59
4615144     800          83028302      87434702   2018-03-13 12:21:24
4615145     800          87434702      87869589   2018-03-13 12:27:56
4615150     800          87869589     100148757   2018-03-14 23:20:07
```

When can I use select that return this result

- when change_date = 2018-03-01 then 83028302 - 88809433
- when change_date = 2018-03-13 then 87869589 - 83028302
- when change_date = 2018-03-01 then 100148757 - 87869589

I want to result

```
select max (new_value) - min(old_value) 
where date = trunc(change_date)
```

Comment: you need a group by...but I'm confused by your logic.  Why does change_date = 2018-03-01 have two different outcomes.  ah, likely a typo.   You are there, change your select statement to include change_date, add a group by change_date and remove the where.

Comment: I want full query, I don't now how to write it, that return result when I want

Comment: Which columns should exist in the select list ?

Comment: all is true in table

Comment: `new_value - old_value`

Comment: i suppose you want to concatenate new_value and old_value like `max (new_value)||' - '||min(old_value)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sql should be enough :

```
select trunc(change_date) "Change Date", 
       to_char(max(new_value))||' - '||to_char(min(old_value)) "Values"
  from cad_changes
 group by trunc(change_date)
 order by trunc(change_date);
```

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: excuse me `values` is a keyword, use `val` instead, or with quoted format like "Values".